# atom-typescript - Why are these Typescript config options not recognised?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

Why am I getting the errors shown in the screenshot below?

Atom says my tsconfig.json 'project file contains invalid options' for allowJs, buildOnSave, and compileOnSave.

But these settings should be allowed: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compileOnSave` and `buildOnSave` do not go under `CompilerOptions`. Like so:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

It appears that `allowJs` is not supported but it will be soon. Here is a branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/d6f11eacc2ec498e192a53f9b935eabfd98fefe9/lib/main/tsconfig/tsconfig.ts), showing that they've already added it, they just haven't merged it yet.

Comment: Since allowJs is supported by the main Typescript compiler it's ok to leave it in your tsconfig.json file. It'll just show an error in Atom, but still work fine when you compile.

Comment: I just made an edit. It looks like allowJs will be added soon.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these options have not been added to Atom TypeScript. Take a look at their interface, it lacks the properties you are having trouble with.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/e2fa67c4715189b71430f766ed9a92d9fb3255f9/lib/main/tsconfig/tsconfig.ts#L8-L35

```
interface CompilerOptions {
    allowNonTsExtensions?: boolean;
    charset?: string;
    codepage?: number;
    declaration?: boolean;
    diagnostics?: boolean;
    emitBOM?: boolean;
    help?: boolean;
    locale?: string;
    mapRoot?: string;                                 // Optionally Specifies the location where debugger should locate map files after deployment
    module?: string;                                  //'amd'|'commonjs' (default)
    noEmitOnError?: boolean;
    noErrorTruncation?: boolean;
    noImplicitAny?: boolean;                          // Error on inferred `any` type
    noLib?: boolean;
    noLibCheck?: boolean;
    noResolve?: boolean;
    out?: string;
    outDir?: string;                                  // Redirect output structure to this directory
    preserveConstEnums?: boolean;
    removeComments?: boolean;                         // Do not emit comments in output
    sourceMap?: boolean;                              // Generates SourceMaps (.map files)
    sourceRoot?: string;                              // Optionally specifies the location where debugger should locate TypeScript source files after deployment
    suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors?: boolean;
    target?: string;                                  // 'es3'|'es5' (default)|'es6'
    version?: boolean;
    watch?: boolean;
}
```